# Use chrome.scripting.insertCSS to inject CSS at document_start with Manifest v3 for a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, browser, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

It used to be possible on Manifest v2 with `chrome.tabs.insertCSS` to inject CSS with
`runAt: document_start` in the details of the object when injecting from the background page

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-insertCSS

This appears to have been removed with Manifest v3's `chrome.scripting.insertCSS` and there doesn't seem to be a runAt option available anymore for CSS from a background page.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-insertCSS

It now seems to default to `document_idle`

Is there another way of doing it?
Putting the CSS file in the manifest file isn't really an option as it needs to create the CSS in the background page.

The new `chrome.scripting` API does let content scripts be injected at `document_start` but not CSS.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: This is yet another use case destroyed by ManifestV3. Currently there's no solution because chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts doesn't accept a literal string for `css`, but only files. The only workaround is to use a JS content script that creates a `style` element in the page.

Comment: BTW how do you construct this css string? There's a possibility for another workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the help, wOxxOm.

I'm currently using

`chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
target: { tabId: tab.tabId },
css: `.mydiv { background-color: red; }`
});`

What I'm doing is if the website is a certain URL it'll construct the CSS and it'll inject it in

Comment: Sorry, it's not letting me edit the previous comment but it's like:
I'm currently using

`chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
target: { tabId: tab.tabId },
css: ".mydiv { background-color: red; }"
});`

Comment: Well just include a css file in your extension with this CSS and register it once using chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts, but that'll work only if the condition is the URL itself.

Comment: https://crbug.com/1303199